# img src variable not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The application is working on dreamweaver but when I try it on Chrome or IE it dones't work. I know where the issue is but I don't now how to fix it. It has something to do with applying variable as an img src. The code is setup at http://jsfiddle.net/v9rxH/

the issue is in the line

```
 $(".topImage").attr("src", "'" + obj[randomNumA].urlTop + "'");
 $(".middleImage").attr("src", "'" + obj[randomNumB].urlMiddle + "'");
 $(".bottomImage").attr("src", "'" + obj[randomNumC].urlBottom + "'");
```

when the browser renders it is show

```
 <img src="'http://placehold.it/300x100&text=SecondBottom'" class="bottomImage">
```

it's adding additional single quotes('  ') in src. Based on that, I removed the single quotes and it shows the variable as text instead of it's value. 
What am I missing? 
Thanks in advance. Rex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're putting the single quotes around it with `"'"` - you don't need to, using `.attr()` handles that for you:

```
$(".topImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumA].urlTop);
$(".middleImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumB].urlMiddle);
$(".bottomImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumC].urlBottom);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove single quotes from `obj[randomNumN].urlTop`.

- See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/v9rxH/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 $(".topImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumA].urlTop);
 $(".middleImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumB].urlMiddle);
 $(".bottomImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumC].urlBottom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
$(".topImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumA].urlTop);
$(".middleImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumB].urlMiddle);
$(".bottomImage").attr("src", obj[randomNumC].urlBottom);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9rxH/2/)** example.